# cypress ci missing libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

Tags: docker, circleci, cypress

I am running Cypress with circle ci. It works when using the orb, but this does not. I am trying to start both of my client server along with node server. It seems like I am missing a package in the docker container or something.

I am willing to change back to use the cypress orb, but I am not sure how to set it up to have both servers running before running `cypress/run`

```
> If you are using Docker, we provide containers with all required dependencies installed.
----------

/home/circleci/.cache/Cypress/3.1.5/Cypress/Cypress: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
----------

Platform: linux (Debian - 8.11)
Cypress Version: 3.1.5
```

Here are the steps:

```
docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/node:10.8.0
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: dnb
      - image: redis
      - image: cypress/base:10
        environment:
          TERM: xterm
steps:
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}
            - v1-deps

      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: npm install

      - save_cache:
          key: v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          # cache NPM modules and the folder with the Cypress binary
          paths:
            - ~/.npm
            - ~/.cache

      # - run:
      #     name: Run test
      #     command: npm test -- --coverage --forceExit --detectOpenHandles --maxWorkers=10
      #     no_output_timeout: 3m

      # - run:
      #     name: Send codecov coverage report
      #     command: bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash) -f coverage/lcov.info -t

      - run:
          name: run client server
          command: npm start
          background: true

      - run:
          name: Pull server
          command: cd && git clone ....git && ls

      - run:
          name: run node server
          command: cd && cd ..i && npm install && npm run dev:prepare && npm start
          background: true

      - run: npm run cypress:run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually executing cypress in the `cypress/base:10` docker image.

See the [CircleCI docs for multiple images](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/#using-multiple-docker-images):

> In a multi-image configuration job, all steps are executed in the container created by the first image listed.

You should try this instead:

```yaml
docker:
  # specify the version you desire here
      - image: cypress/base:10
        environment:
          TERM: xterm
      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: dnb
      - image: redis
```